# Переменные в PHP. Видна ли переменная объявленная через @GLOBALS в других сеансах?

Tags: php

Если я в скрипте объявляю переменную через массив @GLOBALS, видна ли она будет в других сессиях этого скрипта запущенных другими пользователями?

Пример: в переменную записываем некоторое сообщение @GLOBALS['anytext'] = "Hello". Другой пользователь заходит и скрипт пытается считать из этой переменной. Получится ли у него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не будет, потому что все инициализированные переменные, экземпляры классов и состояние самого приложения сохраняются только в течение времени, пока выполняется **текущий скрипт**. При новом обращении к веб-серверу приложение и все переменные инициализируются заново.
Если вам требуется сохранить какую-то информацию, чтобы она была доступна в разных сеансах, то вы можете воспользоваться одним из следующих способов:

1. [Сессии](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php), с помощью глобальной переменной `$_SESSION`.
2. [Запись в файл](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php) и последующее чтение из него.
3. Кэширование данных.
4. Запись в какую-либо таблицу в базе данных.

Какой способ более предпочтительный — зависит уже от формата и объёма данных.

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Она доступна во всех контекстах скрипта. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.globals.php

Если хотите передавать переменную между пользователями, то можно записывать ее в файл или memcache (redis)